# Vuex store state not being updated

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Why is this not updating the store d3 state?

```js
<script>
import HorizontalLinearityGraph from "@/components/HorizontalLinearityGraph";
export default {
  components: {HorizontalLinearityGraph},
  data: () => ({
    model: null,
    d1:[25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250],
    d2:[50,75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275],
    d3:[],
  }),
  methods: {
      d3Fill() {
        for (let i =0; i < 10; i++){
          this.d3[i] = this.d2[i] - this.d1[i];
        }
        this.$store.commit('addHorizontalData', this.d3)
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the mutations for the "addHorizontalData"

```
mutations: {
        addHorizontalData(state, d3){
            state.d3Horizontal(d3)
        }
    },
```

And here is the state. It's just a simple variable as the d1, d2 and d3 on the component.

```
state: {
        d3Horizontal:[],
    },
```

Full Store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)


export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {        
        d3Horizontal:[],
    },
    mutations: {       
        addHorizontalData(state, d3){
            state.d3Horizontal(d3)
        }
    },   
})
```

Comment: where are you firing `d3Fill()`?
It should be `state.d3Horizontal = d3;`

Comment: Thanks mate, it fixed. I'm firing d3Fill when the user wants to create a graph.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably having a console error due to the fact that `d3Horizontal` is an array and not a function, therefore your code should be:

`mutations: { addHorizontalData(state, d3){ state.d3Horizontal = d3; } }`